# Regression Line is Not Plotting When Using Geom_Smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, poisson

I am doing the 5 day regression challenge on Kaggle but I am having trouble getting a poisson regression line to plot when using ggplot. I want to look at the effects of Rain fall on the number of bikes that cross the bridges in NYC.

I have tried reversing the order of geom_point and geom_smooth but that hasn't worked. If I use gaussian instead, that also doesn't work.

Here's what I have written:

```
ggplot(data = bikes, mapping = aes(x = Precipitation, y = Total)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "poisson")) + 
   geom_point() +
   labs(title = 'Precipitation vs. Total Bike Crossings')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the data before plotting it:

```
unique(bikes$Precipitation)
# [1] "0.01"     "0.15"     "0.09"     "0.47 (S)" "0"        "0.2"      "T"       
# [8] "0.16"     "0.24"     "0.05"
```

The regressor `Precipitation` is not numeric and some of its values when coerced to numeric will become `NA` values.

If you coerce `Precipitation` first the regression line shows up.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

bikes %>%
  mutate(Precipitation = as.numeric(Precipitation)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Precipitation, y = Total)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              formula = y ~ x,
              method.args = list(family = "poisson")) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = 'Precipitation vs. Total Bike Crossings')
```

[image]

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks so much Rui!